# Use Xpcom.CreateInstance<IType>(String); in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, geckofx, createinstance

I want to use such a CreateInstance-Function as the following one for GeckoFx in VB.NET.

```
Xpcom.CreateInstance<nsILoginManager>("@mozilla.org/login-manager;1");
```

The code above works fine for C-Sharp but not for VB.NET, what should I use instead?

If I try `Xpcom.CreateInstance(nsILoginManager)("@mozilla.org/login-manager;1")` I get an Error for as the following one :

> "This [nsILoginManager] is a type and cannot be used as Expression"

What else should I write/use?

The reason why I try this is to activate the historisation for fields in the webbrowser-component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB.NET uses `of` keyword to specify type.

Try this:

```
Xpcom.CreateInstance(Of nsILoginManager)("@mozilla.org/login-manager;1")
```